# NSManagedObject subclasses in Swift can not use custom accessor?

Tags: core-data, subclass, nsmanagedobject, accessor

I am using Swift in Core Data generated subclass of NSManagedObject. There is a transient optional property title.(The optional is not Swift's optional, but Core Data's optional.)
So I need a custom getter. My code is

```
class ShoppingList: NSManagedObject {

    @NSManaged var title: String

    func title() -> String {
        return "something"
    }
}
```

The Objective-C version of the getter works fine. However, Xcode tells me that "the func title() is an invalid redeclaration". I tried to use computed property, but get that "@Managed property can not use computed property".

So my question is, is there an alternative way to get custom accessors(getters) in Swift version of NSManagedObject subclassing?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a different name for a computed property, and have it return the title variable.

```
@NSManaged var title: String

var myTitle : String {
   return self.title
}
```

Would that work for you?
Apple does it like this in many places by naming the actual var with an underscore in front, and the computed property with the same name but without the underscore

Comment: What I need is an equivalence of Objective-C version's getter in Core Data's transient property in Swift. Your way is to not define transient property in Core Data Model file but use it directly in source file. I think it should work. But it is not what I want.

Comment: I am not quite sure what the difference is. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: As in my example, the title is a transient property in core data. It is nil when I create a new ShoppingList instance. So I need an getter to generate the title when it been accessed. However, you approach is to ask me to generate something from title, which is nil now. So It is not possible.

Comment: If I use your approach, I have to first dropping the definition of title in core data model. Then create it in source file. This will work. But my model is not completed as the transient property is not defined in the model file.